# Scrypto simulator installtion failure?

Tags: rust, scrypto

I am trying to install the simulator as per the instruction in [here](https://www.scrypto-tutorial.com/getting-started/installation).
I am getting the following failure message:
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it cannot find clang. You should have clang and its development package installed, otherwise this crate cannot build against it, which it apparently needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

Scrypto v0.3 requires you to have `llvm` installed. Please follow these steps to get it installed:

On Windows: use [this installer](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-13.0.1/LLVM-13.0.1-win64.exe)

On Linux: run `sudo apt install llvm`

After installation, don't forget to close and reopen your terminal